# What are the differenced between SuperMicro console terminal types ANSI, VT100 and VT-UTF8

Tags: terminal, bios, console, supermicro

I tried to find a comparison between various terminal types configurable on SuperMicro console to serial BIOS redirection but I was not able to find any.

Can someone make a brief comparison of these?

Defaults seems to be ANSI which is likely to be provide best compatibility and I suspect being a subset of the other two.

I suspect that UTF8 allows use of Unicode charactes which should be nice as this also happens to be what linux uses by default.

Still is not clear to me if these would work well with Linux (CentOS/Fedora/Debian...) or not and which one should I configure for best-experience.

Answer (score 2):

[VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) incorporates [VT52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT52#Escape_sequences) escape sequences with colour extensions. ANSI refers to the use of [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to do the same thing, while [VT-UTF8 is a Microsoft specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-vuvp/969416c0-ccd6-4a75-a9b3-597d7713845b) - which, as you guessed, passes UTF-8.

You may see VT100+, a second Microsoft specification for a colour Windows terminal, described at the same link, which also defines certain function key sequences, but does *not* (as far as I can see) support Unicode.

The Windows specifications, [used by EMS](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174352&seqNum=3), also provide key sequences to start up and reset an attached server.